# callback called only once?

Tags: jquery, callback, nouislider

I'm using the [noUiSlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks), it works but the `on slide` event is called only once and not multiple times.

My code:

```
$("#prix-slider").noUiSlider({
    start: [250,300],
    connect: true,
    margin: 4,
    range: {
        'min': 250,
        'max': 300
    },
    serialization: {
        format: {
            decimals: 0
        }
    }
});
var prixSlider = "#prix-slider";
function updateSliderValues(slider) {
    console.log(slider);
    var sliderValues = $(slider).val();
    console.log(sliderValues[0]);
    console.log(sliderValues[1]);
}
$(prixSlider).on('slide', updateSliderValues(prixSlider) );
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `updateSliderValues(prixSlider)` this will invoke that function isn't..? we have to pass the function's reference right..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `function(){}` to use updateSliderValues

```
$(prixSlider).on('slide', function(){
    updateSliderValues(prixSlider) 
});
```